# Merging Forms Authentication databases together

Tags: authentication, iis-7.5, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net-based system; identical copies of the site run on three different servers, all Windows 2008R2 running IIS7.5. Each site has it's own authentication database, with it's own users, roles, profiles etc.

I'd like to merge these databases together, so that there's one single authentication database shared by the three servers, and then users can log into any of the three servers.

The main site has by far the biggest set of users; the other two sites only have a handful of users/profiles each, so recreating them by hand is possible if necessary. However, what do I need to do to ensure that the password hashing/salt is valid and usable on each server?

Is it just a case of setting identical `MachineKey`s in `web.config`? Do I also need to set identical `ApplicationId`s in the `aspnet_Applications` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merge the smaller two membership tables into the larger, when you migrate the Membership tables into the larger tables you can change the ApplicationID of the new rows to have the same ApplicationID as the first. After doing so you effectively will have 1 big(ger) Application of users which is shared by the 3 applications. Since you are using hashing, (I'll assume your web.config has validation=SHA1), you shouldn't need to worry about the Machine Key, as it is not used for validating logins- that's what the salt is for. The Machine Key is used for encrypting stuff like Session, Form Data, and ViewState. It's OK if the Machine Keys remain different for each of the applications. (If you were load balancing a single application across multiple servers you would need them to be the same.)

Now for some caveats.

- Usernames must be unique in a membership database, so if you have any duplicates across the 3 apps, you'll have to determine how to proceed on a case by case basis. Hopefully if there are duplicates, they are the same person repeating the username on both apps, but that's not necessarily the case. (Two different users could have username "Ken" on different apps, in which case one of them will have to pick a new username.) In the case where it is the same user, they may have different passwords, or emails too, so one will have to win out.
- The same user may have two different accounts on different apps. You'll probably want to use just one of them.
- Emails may be configured to be unique as well, and if so you'll have a similar issue with different usernames having the same email. Though this may actually help you as it will be easier to isolate if the same user has two different accounts.
- Roles will have different RoleIDs and will need to be merged, and also the UsersInRoles entries need to be updated accordingly.
- If you are using the aspnet_Profile table, and if you some users have accounts in more than 1 app, you'll have to figure out how to merge the data. This is actually true of all the tables, but with most of the other tables you'll likely just pick one field from the more popular application (last login date, IsUserLockedOut, etc.) For Profile data though, it must be merged since it contains multiple name/value pairs.
- This should go without saying, but you're going to want to do some pretty extensive testing. My caveats list is by no means exhaustive; plus this obviously could be a breaking change for custom application code.